# ARCore – Image from arFragment is different from the fragment's display

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am working with ARCore in one of my project. I am using the `arFragment` in the view. From that, I use

```
arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame().acquireCameraImage()
```

which returns an `image`. This image and the preview in the fragments displays are **different**. I thought that what I see through the AR fragment is what is captured via `acquireCameraImage`, but  it looks like the acquired image has more part than the fragments display and also the orientation is in landscape (portrait view in fragment`s display).

**I need an image object same as the preview in the fragment`s display.**
Are there any way to get that?

Comment: How do you know they're different?  Please post comparison images & your Manifest's activity declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly wrote – a public method `.acquireCameraImage()` acquires an image from the camera that corresponds to the current frame:

```
public Image acquireCameraImage()
```

In order to obtain the same image object as the preview in the fragment`s display just use:

```
public Frame update()
```

> **Google ARCore developers documentation**:
>
> [update() method](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Session#update()) updates the state of the `ARCore` system. This includes: **receiving a new camera frame**, updating the location of the device, updating the location of tracking anchors, updating detected planes, etc. This call may cause off-screen OpenGL activity. Because of this, to avoid unnecessary frame buffer flushes and reloads, this call should not be made in the middle of rendering a frame or offscreen buffer. This call may update the pose of all created anchors and detected planes. The set of updated objects is accessible through `getUpdatedTrackables(Class)`. This call in blocking mode (see Config.UpdateMode) will wait until a new camera image is available, or until the built-in timeout (currently `66ms`) is reached. If the camera image does not arrive by the built-in timeout, then `update()` will return the most recent Frame object. For some applications it may be important to know if a new frame was actually obtained (for example, to avoid redrawing if the camera did not produce a new frame). To do that, compare the current frame's timestamp, obtained via `getTimestamp()`, with the previously recorded frame timestamp. If they are different, this is a new frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..!!
I solved this issue using  the scaling and rotation for the the generated bitmap. But it  was very hard to found the aspect pixel ratio.

Comment: Hi @AngathanNesarasa, how to convert landscape image to portrait image received from acquireCameraImage(). Can you provide me the code?

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. In my case my phone's screen resolution is 1920x1080, whereas the YUV image I get from the `acquireCameraImage` is 640x480. It's not just it's smaller than the screen, but it's not even the right aspect ratio. My application is full screen, therefore I'd expect (and I also need) a frame buffer with the same 16:9 aspect ratio. I'm scratching my head what is that frame buffer for exactly, or what is this 640x480?

Comment: I wrote a question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227417/how-to-obtain-screen-aspect-ratio-camera-image-in-an-arcore-application

Comment: @AngathanNesarasa can you please post the function for your calculations?