# How to obtain screen aspect ratio unaugmented camera image in an ARCore application?

Tags: java, kotlin, android-camera, arcore, screen-capture

I'm working on an augmented reality application based on ARCore. I'd need to capture the screen to perform some extra manipulation, which wouldn't be a real time manipulation so it won't be in the OpenGL / shader level.

I'm calling the ARCore frame's `acquireCameraImage` https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Frame#acquireCameraImage()
It returns a YUV_420_888 image but the dimensions are unexpected (to me). My phone's screen has 1920x1080 resolution (16:9 aspect ratio). The returned YUV Image from the API has a 640x480 resolution (4:3 aspect ratio). I'd need to access the unaugmented screen resolution (or at least aspect ratio) image.

What's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @JaswantSingh I'm cropping / resizing. That's also not trivial because available code uses various (but all mostly deprecated) libraries.